# Android emulator - problems with SD option

Tags: android-emulator

I'm having a difficult time with the sdcard option in the Android emulator, on eclipse.  It's Eclipse 3.4 on windows. It accepts the timezone option, that is in run configurations, target, the cmd line option is currently '-sdcard c://mysdcard -timezone "America/New_York"'

I've variations on the path, but when I try to save an image from the emulator browser window, It give me a "no sd card found" message.

I've checked google and android docs, also tried placing an image in android_sdk_windows, android_sdk_windows,/tools/ only specifying the image, and in each of the platforms. I also specified int in the eclipse preferences, still no luck.

This should be straightforward, but I'm just starting out with Android. Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

Here's the syntax

-sdcard c:\mysdcard.iso -timezone "America/New_York"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with Eclipse (maybe it does that for you), but from the command line, you should use the 'mksdcard' tool that comes with the SDK